# Javascript class scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to call this.RenderDeals() from inside my Post.success function. I assume this has something to do with scope? Could someone shed some light on the issue, and possibly suggest a workaround. I have tried using prototype and module pattern, both without any luck.

FYI Post is an $.ajax wrapper that returns a jQuery Deferred object.

```
    function Deals() {
        this.template = '#trTemplate';
        this.container = '#containerTable';
        this.GetDeals = function () {
            Post('Deal.svc/GetDeals')
            .success(function (result) {
                this.RenderDeals(result);
            });
        };
        this.RenderDeals = function (deals) {
            $(this.template).tmpl(deals).appendTo(this.container);
        }
    }


    var deal = new Deals();
    deal.GetDeals();
```

UPDATE:

Ok, so I added the following line just above the GetDeals function:

```
var me = this;
```

and instead call

```
me.RenderDeals(result);
```

Appears to work correctly, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: That works because you've defined 'me' and then used it.  But using 'this' directly is going to give you an instance of something else, because you're in a different context/scope.

Comment: just an FYI thing, in javascript idioms, a function starting with a capital means it is a constructor function. Not a problem or anything, but it just looks odd to someone who is a javascript guy but not a .net guy

Comment: @Matt maybe I'll start a revolution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` reference in your "success" function almost certainly isn't what you think it is.  Try this change:

```
function Deals() {
    var instance = this;

    this.template = '#trTemplate';
    this.container = '#containerTable';
    this.GetDeals = function () {
        Post('Deal.svc/GetDeals')
        .success(function (result) {
            instance.RenderDeals(result);
        });
    };
    this.RenderDeals = function (deals) {
        $(this.template).tmpl(deals).appendTo(this.container);
    }
}
```

By stashing a reference to `this` in the "instance" variable, your handler will have a guaranteed way of getting back to the relevant instance when calling the other function ("RenderDeals").

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there are no classes in javascript, only objects. This may sound strange, but you can still do OOP without them in javascript :) I suggest you read up on this.

You are correct about the scope issue, the `this` keyword has some strange behavior. Read [this](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this) for some more info.

Look into using the `prototype` attribute of any function object. I prefer to do my javascript OOP in the following fashion:

```
function Deals(){
    //this is your constructor
    var me = this;
    //this way you can avoid having to search the DOM every time you want to reference
    //your jquery objects.
    me.template = $('#trTemplate');
    me.container = $('#containerTable');
}
Deals.prototype.getDeals = function(){
    var me = this;
    Post('Deal.svc/GetDeals')
    .success(function (result) {
        me.RenderDeals(result);
    })
}
Deals.prototype.renderDeals = function(){
    var me = this;
     me.template.tmpl(deals).appendTo(me.container);
}
```

By declaring `var me = this;` at the top of each prototype function, you create a closure that refers to the object of interest, even inside of a callback :)

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to mention that you would use the Deals object like this: `var deals = new Deals(); deals.renderDeals();`

Comment: Thanks for the alternative pattern. To be honest, I don't know if I really need to be doing any of this. I'm never going need many instances of the object, I was just trying to encapsulate a particular piece of my pages functionality to make it cleaner and more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not define RenderDeals() outside of Deals()?

```
    function RenderDeals(dealsObj, dealsData) {
        $(dealsObj.template).tmpl(dealsData).appendTo(dealsObj.container);
    }
```

Then instead of this:

```
this.RenderDeals(result);
```

Do this:

```
RenderDeals(this, result);
```

Comment: Because I am trying to encapsulate the functionality in a single class.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want it to be globally visible?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't obvious because it wasn't specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Deals = {
    template: $('#trTemplate'),
    container: $('#containerTable'),
    init: function (){
        return Deals;
    }
    GetDeals: function () {
        Post('Deal.svc/GetDeals')
        .success(function (result) {
            Deals.RenderDeals(result);
        })
    },
    RenderDeals = function (deals) {
        Deals.template.tmpl(deals).appendTo(Deals.container);
    }
}

var deal = Deals.init();
deal.GetDeals();
```

Comment: Maybe he really wants to be able to construct many of these instances.

Comment: this will work, but imo pointy has a better answer by using a closure to capture the value of this.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is a scoping issue. Pointy has the right answer, but I thought I could fill in a bit of what is going on.

`this` in javascript is an implicit variable that is set to whatever the function is attached to by default (or the global object if it isn't attached to anything). When you pass your function as a param into Post#success, it is not attached to any instance, let alone the current instance of Deals.

Pointy has the best answer here, what he is doing is creating an explicit variable that captures the implicit variable of `this` of deals. One of the coolest features of javascript is that everything that is in scope of a function definition will also be in scope for a function invocation, so by making that variable, you are able to access it again later, whenever and however that anonymous function is called.